# How to Sum the duration in Gridview List by using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: vb.net, linq

How you doing today? Wish you all good.

By the way, here is my problem. I would like to display the total of sum duration in gridview by using LINQ to SQL. I have two tables, Users and Log_Times

Users
UserID-----Name
1------------Bob
2------------Mary
3------------Jane
Log_Times
ID---------------UserID--------------------TimeIn---------------------TimeOut
1--------------------1-----------------------1/1/2009 10:00:00-------1/1/2009 11:05:00
2--------------------2-----------------------1/1/2009 10:00:00-------1/1/2009 11:02:30
3--------------------3-----------------------1/1/2009 10:00:00-------1/1/2009 11:00:00
4--------------------1-----------------------1/2/2009 10:00:00-------1/2/2009 11:05:00
5--------------------2-----------------------1/2/2009 10:00:00-------1/2/2009 11:02:30

There would be so great, if our gentle man can generate report which looks like this:
UserName-------TotalDuration
Bob---------------2 Hours, 10 Minutes 
Mary--------------2 Hours, 5 Minutes
Jane--------------1 Hour 

I am using LINQ to SQL and VB.NET.

The code I have so far is:

Dim db = new LogTimeDataContext
Dim LogUser = from lu in db.Users select lu.Name, TotalDuration = ? ? ?
Gridview1.DataSource = LogUser
Gridview1.DataBind()

Please and please help me to figure out what is behind this TotalDuration code..

I really appreciate for taking your valuable time to pass through this problem and Im looking forward for the best response toward it. Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which is working fine is this.

```
Imports System.Data.Linq.SqlClient 

Dim QueryLogUser = from u in db.Users 
Select u.Name, Duration = u.Log_Times.Select (Function(lt) SqlMethods.DateDiffSecond(lt.TimeIn, lt.TimeOut))

Dim LogUser = From u In QueryLogUser.AsEnumerable _
Select u.Name, TotalDuration = u.Duration.Sum Order By TotalDuration Descending
```

By this I can get the total second. Then I will write one more function in gridview later to convert from Second into minutes and hour.

```
Dim totalSecond as Integer
Dim totalMinute as Integer
Dim totalHour as Integer

Protected Function FieldDisplayDuration(ByVal Second As Integer)
 Dim d As String = "DefaultValue"
 If (Second > 60)
   totalSecond = Second mod 60
   totalMinutes = Second / 60
   If (totalMinutes > 60)
      totalHour = totalMinute mod 60
      totalMinute = totalMinute + totalMinute mod 60
      return totalHour & totalMinute & totalSecond
   End If
   return totalMinute & totalSecond
 End If
 return totalSecond

End Function
```

In this way, I could get my duration column in the format of Hour, Minute, and Second.Happy coding :)

Comment: If returning all users is the requirement - your answer is correct. You can also combine your queries into a single one. See my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry for replying late... I was having a vacation without internet connection. Thanks a lot geoff for the comment. Take care and have a nice day.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this

```
from t in db.Log_Times 
join u in db.Users on t.UserID equals u.UserID 
select new {user = u.name, Sum(t.TimeOut - t.TimeIn) AS Duration };
```

I don't know if the sum part is correct but it's maybe the sort of route you'd like to go down.

I'm sure someone more experienced in SQL could modify the query to be correct.

Comment: Hi Dean. I think your query could give me only the list of the user who appears in Log_Times only. The point is to get every single user even though they haven't log in or log out yet. But they are exist in Users table. Thanks you very much for trying.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

```
Dim QueryLogUser = from u in db.Users 
                   Select u.Name, Duration = u.Log_Times.Select (Function(lt) SqlMethods.DateDiffSecond(lt.TimeIn, lt.TimeOut)).Sum).OrderbyDescending(function(o) o.Duration)
```

The Query below only returns users who have an entry in the Log_times table.

```
Imports System.Data.Linq.SqlClient

Dim db = New LogTimeDataContext
Dim LogUser = From log In db.Log_Times _
              Group By _
                 Name = log.User.Name _
              Into _
                 Duration = Sum(SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute(log.TimeIn,log.TimeOut) _
              Select name, TotalDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(If(Duration,0)).tostring
```

The final line just checks that the duration is not nothing before converting to a timespan

Comment: Hello there, Nice trying. However, if I have one more user who never  log in and out. It could give us only the report of the only users who stay in Log_Times table only.

Comment: Oh yes. You are very logistic geoff! It works like charm. Thanks geoff! Happy coding.